# Typescript / JavaScript compare undefined values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

by http method Im downloading dto with some variables and some of them may be undefined.

example Http response (it may contains more variables like SO2, C6H6 etc...):

```
{
  'city_name': 'warszawa',
  'pollution_types': {
    'CO': 506.0,
    'O3': 52.66
  }
}
```

Dtos:

```
export interface PollutionTypes {
  CO: number;
  NO2: number;
  SO2: number;
  PM10: number;
  PM25: number;
  C6H6: number;
  O3: number;
}

export interface AirQualityData {
  city_name: string;
  pollution_types: PollutionTypes;
}
```

At this moment Im trying to compare this in this way but it doesnt work.

```
tmp = pollutionTypes.map(value => value.CO);
if (tmp != undefined || tmp != null) {
  //do something
}
```

When Im trying to display this object on console Im getting something like that:

```
[undefined]
0: undefined
length: 1
```

But this is not equal to undefined :/

Do u know how to solve this? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: what is the value in pollutionTypes property?

Comment: its a datastructure for few numbers that are in API response

Comment: please give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the correct thing in your console, it shows you that you get an array. The contents just happens to be `undefined`.

```js
const arrayWithUndefined = [undefined];
console.log(arrayWithUndefined);
```

You could filter your array and remove undefined values. And then see if your array has values in it.

```js
const types = {
  "city_name": "warszawa",
    "pollution_types": {
        "O3": 52.66
    }
}; // NO CO present in this data to simulate undefined.
const pollutionTypes = [types.pollution_types];

tmp = pollutionTypes.map(value => value.CO);

console.log('Before filter:', tmp);

tmp = tmp.filter(function( element ) {
   return element !== undefined;
});

console.log('After filter:', tmp);

if (tmp.length) { // Check if tmp has values in it.
  console.log('tmp has elements in it');
  //do something
} else {
  console.log('tmp is empty');
}
```

This will return `tmp is empty` because no CO values where in the array.

Answer (score 1):

let us go through the problems proposed in your question, though it might be more useful to add more information such as sample data of your `pollutionTypes` variable.

Let us begin:

```
// So currently you have the following mapping code...
tmp = pollutionTypes.map(value => value.CO);
//                                ^^^^^^
// The problem is that you are mapping an array that does not have the field
// you are referencing in the mapping function. So it will map for sure,
// its just that it will return an array of undefined values of the same
// size as the array

if (tmp != undefined || tmp != null) {
    //...
}
// and apparently when you log tmp, you get [undefined]
```

So here is a proposed explanation and solution:

```
/*
 * The map function is called on arrays, it allows you to convert an array
 * of size N to a new array of the same size N by parsing it a mapping function
 * that allows you to manipulate and return derived elements of each element in the
 * old array.
 */
// [TIP]: so first we should use const when defining tmp
const tmp = pollutionTypes.map(value => value.CO);
//                                      ^^^^^^
// So generally try making sure that your data has the CO field
// before mapping...because you're just gonna get an array of undefined
// fields

// [TIP]: you do not need to specify the undefined logic
if (tmp) {
    //...
}
```

Can you add more information on what `pollutionTypes` is so a better solution
can come up. Anyway, hope this helps.